# SQL Server 2012 Error 9512 when modifying user login

Tags: sql-server-2012, permissions, security, logins

We are attempting to grant access to a database to one of our employees. We open up his user properties in Security -> Logins, navigate to the `User Mappings` page, select the database, select `db_owner` in the options below, set the default schema to `dbo`, then when we click `OK` to save the changes, we get the following error:

> Create failed for User 'domain\username'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>   
> Xml data type is not supported as a parameter to remote calls. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 9512)

Any thoughts on why we may be getting this error and what we can do to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have a DDL trigger that is set to listen for `ALTER_LOGIN` events, and is trying to pass `EVENTDATA()` directly to some remote procedure.

Check for this using:

```
USE master;
GO
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION([object_id]) 
  FROM sys.server_triggers
  WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION([object_id]) LIKE N'%ALTER[_]LOGIN%';
```

It could also be a database-level DDL trigger that listens for `ALTER_USER`:

```
USE the_relevant_database;
GO
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION([object_id]) 
  FROM sys.triggers
  WHERE parent_class = 0
  AND OBJECT_DEFINITION([object_id]) LIKE N'%ALTER[_]USER%';
```

Comment: Turns out someone put a change window trigger on there that only allows schema changes to that database after hours. Temporarily disabling that trigger did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: @smoothgrips Glad it helped. They should probably consider changing the trigger so that a more intuitive error is raised (or maybe security through obscurity is the goal).